# find domain name using email address from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am in org where person can have multiple email address for example

if user alias = alias1 he will have for sure one email address as alias1@org.com
at the same time he might have other email address fname.lname123@org.com

Also my org has multiple active directory domain like NorthAmerica, EASTASIA, etc.

I want to find to which active directory domain the user belongs.
Using below code I am able to figure out domain for all emails of type alias@org.com
but for other types of email the code is unable to find record in active directory.

```
    string[] emails = new string[]{"alias1@org.com", "fname.lname@org.com"};
    string[] DOMAINS = new string[] { "DOMAIN1", "DOMAIN2"};
    PrincipalContext[] contexts = new PrincipalContext[DOMAINS.Length];
    for (int i=0; i<DOMAINS.Length; i++)
    {
        contexts[i] = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DOMAINS[i]);
    }
    foreach (string email in emails)
    {
        string myDomain = "Not found";
        for(int i=0; i<DOMAINS.Length; i++)
        {

            UserPrincipal yourUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(contexts[i], email);

            if (yourUser != null)
            {
                myDomain = DOMAINS[i];'
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(email + " " + myDomain);

    }
```

for alias1@org.com i was able to find the active directory domain but not for the other case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()` cannot actually search by email address. It can only search by one of the identifier types in the [`IdentityType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.identitytype). In your case, it's probably matching by `UserPrincipalName`, which is why you find results sometimes, but not all.

For this, I would use `DirectorySearcher` directly, which is what `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()` uses behind the scenes anyway, but you have more control over how you search.

You would have to search by the [`proxyAddresses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-proxyaddresses) attribute. All of the user's email addresses will be there, prefixed by `smtp:` (the primary address is uppercase `SMTP:`). That would look something like this:

```cs
string[] emails = new string[]{"alias1@org.com", "fname.lname@org.com"};
string[] DOMAINS = new string[] { "DOMAIN1", "DOMAIN2"};
foreach (string email in emails)
{
    string myDomain = "Not found";
    for(int i=0; i<DOMAINS.Length; i++)
    {

        var searcher = new DirectorySearcher {
            SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{DOMAINS[i]}"),
            Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(proxyAddresses=smtp:{email}))",
            PropertiesToLoad = { "cn" } //just put something so it doesn't return everything
        };

        if (searcher.FindOne() != null)
        {
            myDomain = DOMAINS[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(email + " " + myDomain);
}
```

If all of the domains that you're searching are all in the same AD forest, then you can save time by querying the Global Catalog once, and not make separate queries on each domain. The Global Catalog stores data for all the domains in the forest. You target a Global Catalog by using `GC://` instead of `LDAP://`.

Then you can ask for the user's [`msDS-PrincipalName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-msds-principalname) attribute, which will be the username in `DOMAIN\username` format, so you can pull the domain name from that. For example:

```cs
string[] emails = new string[]{"alias1@org.com", "fname.lname@org.com"};
foreach (string email in emails)
{
    string myDomain = "Not found";
    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher {
        SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("GC://example.com"),
        Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(proxyAddresses=smtp:{email}))",
        PropertiesToLoad = { "msDS-PrincipalName" }
    };

    var found = searcher.FindOne();
    if (found != null)
    {
        var mdDsPrincipalName = (string) found.Properties["msDS-PrincipalName"][0];
        myDomain = mdDsPrincipalName.Substring(0, mdDsPrincipalName.IndexOf("\\"));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(email + " " + myDomain);
}
```

Just replace `example.com` with the name of any of your domains (doesn't matter which).

Comment: thanks @Gabriel Luci. 
I tested the above code, for some users the found.Properties contains entry with msDS-PrincipalName = domain\alias and also one prop with key = adspath but for other the fouhd.Properties contains only adspath.

Comment: Is it on a specific domain that it doesn't show up? The `msDS-PrincipalName` attribute was introduced in Windows Server 2008. So if that domain is running on an older server, it won't have that attribute.

Comment: Cool then I will parse adspath and get the domain.